# Compiling rabbitmq-c on windows 7: "Looking for htonll - not found"

Tags: visual-studio-2012, rabbitmq, linkage

I'm trying to compile rabbitmq-c on a visual studio 2012 machine, with no success.

I'm following the instructions described in the readme:

```
mkdir build && cd build
cmake ..
cmake --build .
```

However compiling returns a bunch of errors as the following:

```
C:\rabbitmq-c-master\librabbitmq\amqp_private.h(277): error C2375: 'htonll' : redefinition; different linkage
```

I've noticed that when i run the command "cmake .." I get "Looking for htonll - not found". 
So for some reason rabbitmq-c doesn't find my htonll function and tries to redeclare it.

How do I debug this?

A link to the rabbitmq-c library:
https://github.com/alanxz/rabbitmq-c

Comment: You can temporarily jump over it by commenting out the `#ifndef HAVE_HTONLL` block

Comment: having the same issue. anyone have solved the issue?